# F-statistic and p-values plots with lag

Tags: model-selection, granger-causality

I am currently working on multivariate predictive models and have generated several diagrams to represent F-statistics and p-values for different models across various lags. I would greatly appreciate any feedback or insights you may have on the following aspects of my analysis:

```
Lag Selection and Model Performance:
```

Have I selected an appropriate range of lags for analyzing the predictive power of these models?
Does the trend in the F-statistics charts align with common expectations for temporal data analysis?

Overall, is my approach correct? Does my chart offer appropriate information? Is there any other way to produce this visual stimuli.[image]

Based on my AIC and BIC for different VAR(p) models i found the best model for my data is for p=25. I am ,kind of, trying to confirm that

Comment: Your p-value plots show that you are running out of range at the bottom end. (And the p-value is much more sensibly scaled logarithmically.) Given the one-to-one relationship between an F-statistical and the p-value when the degrees of freedom are fixed, do the p-values add any information? (I have no idea what the data are for the graphs...)